# Tomcat Monitoring - connectionCount JMX mbean

Tags: java, tomcat, threadpool, jmx, mbeans

**Question 1:**

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790303/tomcat-thread-monitoring-mbeans-description) describes what is the currentTheadBusy and the currentThreadCount mbeans, but there is the connectionCount mbean.

In this moment, the values of this 3 mbeans on my production Tomcat Application are:

```
currentTheadBusy: 1  
currentThreadCount: 36  
connectionCount: 249
```

Why are there so much more connections than threads? How I read this values?

**Question 2:**

How the connectionCount is related with the Manager/localhost/myapp/**activeSessions** mbean? The current value of this mbean is 1125. Are those values related or I am missing the concept?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connectionCount` is the number of connections the connector has handled, and is largely irrelevant. Clients will typically make a connection, make several requests through that connection, and then close the connection. If you have a reverse-proxy like Apache httpd, nginx, etc., then there may be a single connection handling huge numbers of requests over time.

> Why are there so much more connections than threads?

Because a thread pool with a small number of threads can handle a lot of work over time, especially if overall load it low. If you get 1 request per second all day long and no request takes longer than 1s to complete, then a single thread can handle 100% of your load. If each client makes a 1 connection for 1 request and then closes the connection, that will be `1 * 60 * 60 * 24` = `86400` connections handled by a single thread during a 24-hour period.

If your requests take just less than 1s to complete, then you can handle 86400 requests per day with a single thread. You can handle `2 * 86400` = `172800` connections/requests per day with only one additional thread in your thread pool (from 1 to 2 threads).

> How the connectionCount is related with the Manager/localhost/myapp/activeSessions?

It is not related.

> [Am I] missing the concept?

The `manager` MXBean tracks HTTP session management. You currently have 1125 active sessions in your application.

Have a look at the fine presentations on [Tomcat's presentations](http://tomcat.apache.org/presentations.html) page. Specifically, search for "monitoring".